# Auth on server side from an isomorphic js app

Tags: authentication, reactjs, passport.js, isomorphic-javascript, react-starter-kit

Hi I'm working on a isomorphic react app that uses passport.js for auth.

My problem is requests can come from the client, or from the server. If the request comes from the client, it's authenticated and all is good. BUT, if the request comes from the server, then the auth fails :(

Server (lots removed for sake of clarity):

```
server.use('/api/data', require('./api/data'));
server.get('*', async (req, res, next) => {
    await Router.dispatch({ path: req.path, query: req.query, context }, (state, component) => {
        <div>
          {component}
        </div>
      );
      data.css = css.join('');
    });
});
```

/api/data:

```
router.get('/', auth.isAuthenticated, async (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(200).send({result: 'working!'});
});
```

Routes:

```
  on('/route', async (state, next) => {

    // RESP IS A REJECTED RESPONSE :(
    const resp = await fetch('/api/data');
    const data = await resp.json();

    return <Component data={data} />;
  });
```

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Did you ever find a solution to this?